# IFS Statement satisfies conditions from multiple sheets, get value from array EXCEL VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to compare production data with demand data and updated to another sheet. I have copied all the demand data information I need, but I need to get the production value per item and week.

On the update sheet I have two different IDs from the same SKU (Column A and B) and the demand is by week (Column G). I need to get the production value that satisfies the SKU ID and the week # from the production data. I have tried many codes, but I am not able to make it work. I have attached two screenshots of this data.

Update sheet:
[image]

Production data:
[image]

I have written the following code, but I am not sure what function I need to use to copy the value from the production array.

```
Sub ProductionData()

Dim PDws As Worksheet, DSTws As Worksheet

Set PDws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Production Data")
 LastColumn = PDws.Cells(1, PDws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
 lastrowid1 = .Cells(.Row.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
 
Set DSTws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Direct Ship Tool")
lastrowwk = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row
lastrowid2 = .Cells(.Row.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row


For i = 2 To lastrowwk
For j = 4 To LastColumn
    For Z = 3 To lastrowid1
        For k = 2 To lastrowid2
            If PDws.Cells(j, 1).Value = DSTws.Cells(7, i) Then
                If PDws.Cells(1, Z).Value = DSTws.Cells(1, k) Then
End Sub
```

Any ideas?

Thank you

Comment: Can you give an example of a successful output? I am struggling to understand the desired result from your description.

Comment: If the aim is to populate Col D in the first screenshot, you can use a formula for that.  Use MATCH() to get the row/column positions you need, then feed those into OFFSET() to get the required Production value.. Kind of like this: https://www.excel-easy.com/examples/two-way-lookup.html